# How does the compiler choose between multiple main functions in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a gtest project A for testing my own code (with its gtest `main` function being the program's entry point by default). I compiled my own code into a static library and use this library as an input dependency for my testing project. The "abnormal" thing here is that there is another `main` function in my own code.

I didn't mean to have two main() functions in one program but I don't want to either copy my own code to gtest project to do DT or split my own project into several small pieces without main() function in them.

The gtest project's compilation turned out to be just fine with two main functions (one being the "linked one" though, actually I don't know how this can happen?). I set the gtest project as my startup project in VS2017. And when I run the program, VS2017 automatically chose my own `main` function (not the gtest main) as program's entry point. This behavior is not logical because it's supposed to start the gtest project because it is the "startup project".

And if there could be two main functions in one C++ program, how does the compiler choose which one is being run first?

Comment: Why do you have your own main() in a static library? That's a bug!

Comment: This is an ODR violation -> UB.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Then how do you perform a UT on your own code? Do I have to delete my own main() function? Since I am using gtest.

Comment: Usually the linker will reject two versions of `main`.

Comment: Why would you need a main() function to run a unit test?  The test runner would have its own main().

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because I compiled my own code into a static library and by this method I don't need to copy my code to the test runner

Comment: I perform UT by having a shared library with the relevant code, or a static library that is linked against the driver (i.e. `main()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It doesn't.**

If you try to produce an executable with two functions of identical signature and external linkage, `main` or something else, your linker should tell you that there are duplicate definitions and fail the build.

I suppose it could go undiagnosed in some cases (such as providing [distinct overloads](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2)) but that doesn't make it right, and the results could be anything.

A static (or dynamic) library should not contain a `main`, ever. There is nothing about unit testing that requires you to do that.

> I don't want to *[..]* split my own project into several small pieces without main() function in them.

Why not? That is the normal, commonplace, proper way to design modular software. This problem you're experiencing is just one reason why.

`main()` is the entrypoint to a program, not a trigger point for every individual piece of functionality within it. In your case, the entrypoint is the test runner, and it should be able to access your functionality via the appropriate classes and functions that you created in your library.

Comment: I agree with you on separating main() function with other parts of the program being the proper way to design modular software. And I guess that is why a library should always just be a pure library and nothing else.

Comment: There are two forms of `main()` function, one with parameters and one without. My own main() function has no parameter in it and gtest's `main (argc, *argv[])` function has. Could this be the reason why the compiler thinks that they are different?

Comment: @OrionNebular Yes, it could. You are still violating [the rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2) though.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you say, you are testing your program and in this case the main function is another than the "main" function, turning de unit into a lib for import and test, what do you need to do is to enclose the original main function inside preprocessor directives in for compile time, something like this for main program:

```
#ifndef TESTSUITE
int main(){
... original main function aka your program ...
}
#endif
```

finally you instruct to compile with the define macro command -D:

```
g++ -DTESTSUITE
```

and the second main function for testing:

```
#ifdef TESTSUITE
int main(){
... testing main function ...
}
#endif
```